# Let $f(x)$ be continuous on $[0,2]$, and differentiable on $(0,2)$ such that $0<f(1)<f(0)<f(2)$. Prove that $f'$ has a solution on $(0,2)$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, proof-verification

> Let $f(x)$ be continuous on $[0,2]$, and differentiable on $(0,2)$ such that $0<f(1)<f(0)<f(2)$. Prove that $f'$ has a solution on $(0,2)$.

Here's a little crappy sketch:

[image]

My attempt:

From $f(1)<f(0)<f(2)$ and continuity, there's a point $c\in (1,2)$ such that $f(c)=f(0)$, $f$ is continuous on $[0,c](\subseteq[0,2])$, differentiable on $(0,c)(\subseteq(0,2))$ so from Rolle's we know that there's some $k\in (0,c)$ such that $f'(k)=0$.

Is this alright? Is there another way to do this? Maybe with Lagrange's MVT?

Note: no integration or Taylor's.

Comment: Yes, it's all right. Alternatively, note that $f$ attains its minimum in $(0,2)$, hence ...

Comment: @DanielFischer thanks, what is the argument for that?

Comment: Since $f$ is continuous, it attains its minimum in $[0,2]$. The given inequalities tell you that the minimum is not attained in either $0$ or $2$.

Comment: @DanielFischer and from EVT: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extreme_value_theorem if the extrema isn't at the ends then then the derivative must vanish at least once on that interval?

Comment: If a differentiable function has a local extremum in an open interval, its derivative vanishes there - that is, by the way, what usually is used to prove Rolle's theorem. And a _global_ minimum in an open interval is certainly a _local_ extremum.

Comment: @DanielFischer: In my language we usually call what you said [Fermat's theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat%27s_theorem_%28stationary_points%29). I gather in English that denomination is not used very often?

Comment: @DanielFischer Isn't it enough to notice that $f$ is differentiable almost everywhere on this interval, and it first decreases and then increases, so $f'$ changes the sign hence has a solution?

Comment: @Alex No, we need differentiability everywhere, differentiability almost everywhere isn't sufficient: consider $f(x) = \bigl\lvert x - \frac{2}{3}\bigr\rvert.$

Comment: @DanielFischer I see. In this example derivate does change sign, but doesn't have a solution, that's good. But doesn't the fact that it's not differentiable $only$ at endpoints help?

Comment: @Alex Yes, the endpoints can't destroy it, by "everywhere" I meant "everywhere on the interior". If we have that, so that $f'$ can't have a hole where it jumps, your argument works: since $f(1) < f(0)$, we have an $a\in (0,1)$ with $f'(a) < 0$ by the mean value theorem, ditto we have a $b\in (1,2)$ with $f'(b) > 0$, and the intermediate value theorem for derivatives (Darboux' theorem) then says that $f'$ has a zero in $(a,b)$.

Comment: @DanielFischer: but that's what the problem says, doesn't it? Differentiable everywhere except at endpoint, i.e. 'everywhere on the interior'-?

Comment: @Alex Yes, but you wrote "differentiable almost everywhere", and "almost everywhere" is not sufficient. It needs to be a particular case of almost everywhere. It seems you meant the correct thing and just expressed the condition in too great generality.

Comment: @DanielFischer: you are right, it was a misuse of notation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By the Intermediate Value Theorem there exists a point $c \in (1, 2)$ such that
$$f(c) = f(0),$$
since by hypothesis $f(1) < f(0) < f(2)$.

Applying Rolle's theorem on the interval $[0, c]$ yields the desired result.

---

By Weierstrass' Extreme Value Theorem, the continuous function $f$ attains either a maximum or a minimum $m$ in $[0, 2]$. By hypothesis $m \in (0, 2)$. Since $f$ is differentiable, by Fermat's theorem it must satisfy
$$f'(m) = 0.$$

Comment: Technically you're using IVT, not MVT. The Rolle's theorem application is correct, however.

Comment: @Ian: Oh sorry, in  my language the names are very similar! I confused the two, you are absolutely right!

Comment: @GinKin: Since the first one is basically the same as yours I added a second way to prove the statement.

Comment: Yes thank you that's what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Since $f$ is continuous and $[0,2]$ is compact, $f$ attains its global minimum at some point $x_0\in[0,2]$. As $f(1)<f(0)$ and $f(1)<f(2)$, we see that in fact $x_0\in(0,2)$. As we have a minimum in an open intervall, we conclude $f'(x_0)=0$.

Answer (score 1):

After discussion with Daniel Fischer I decided to leave this as an answer.

First thing to notice is that $f$ is not differentiable only at endpoints, hence it's differentiable everywhere in the interior of $I=(a,b)$.

Secondly, since $f(1)<f(0)$ and $f(1) <f(2)$, either of two intervals exist: 
$$
I_1 = [\alpha, \beta] \ \text{s.t.} 0<\alpha<\beta \leq 1\\
I_2 = [\gamma, \delta] \ \text{s.t.} 1 \leq \gamma <\delta < 1
$$
where $f$ has a critical point, and at this critical point it is differentiable (it can also be $f(1)$, hence the weak inequality above). Since it is differentiable, $f'$ is continuous and changes sign $\to \ f'$ has a solution in at least 1 point in $I$.

Comment: Just realized it's a variation of Hagen von Eitzen's solution without advanced tools like compactness